# Spawn child_process with pipe (Node)

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, spawn

I am actually stuck on my code and don't really know what's happening.

I am trying to use child process to listen on a pocsag frequency and send the results to multimon-ng to be able to decode the message. Considering the following code :

```
const ps = spawn('rtl_fm', ['-s', '22050', '-f', frequency + 'M']);
const grep = spawn('multimon-ng', ['-t', 'raw', '-a', 'POCSAG512', '-a', 'POCSAG1200', '-a', 'POCSAG2400', '-f', 'alpha /dev/stdin']);

ps.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(data.toString())
  grep.stdin.write(data);
});

grep.stdin.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(data.toString())
  // DO SPECIFIC STUFF WITH DECODED DATA FROM MULTIMON
});
```

One error occurs :

> Cannot call write after a stream was destroyed

What am I missing ?

Thank !